# How to get Server Collation in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2008-r2

How to get the **Server Collation** in SQL Server 2008 R2 with a stored procedure ?

I can't access the *server properties*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`sp_helpsort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175986.aspx) system stored procedure to return the server default collation. This returns a textual description of the collation.

There are some circumstances where `sp_helpsort` returns an empty string, or you may want the collation code. Using

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY ('Collation');
```

may be of more use to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT name, collation_name
FROM sys.databases
WHERE database_id = DB_ID()
```

Doesn't access any of the "server properties" but just selects what you're interested in from the system catalog views.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any special permissions to get the server collation because it is used to set the collation of the system databases, one of which is `tempdb`, and everyone has access to see those details:

```sql
SELECT sd.[collation_name] AS [ServerCollation]
FROM [sys].[databases] sd
WHERE sd.[name] = N'tempdb';
```